# android listview

Tags: android, listview, onclick

if it works will be the first application.
There are about 290 items. opens a new page is clicked. but the "switch" or "if" after the error is over 250. What could be the reason?

```
if (position == 0) {
    Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, otobus5.class);
    startActivity(newActivity);
} else if (position == 1) {
    Intent newActivity6 = new Intent(this, otobus6.class);
    startActivity(newActivity6);
}
.
.
.
if (position == 290) {
    Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, otobus290.class);
    startActivity(newActivity);
} else if (position == 291) {
    Intent newActivity6 = new Intent(this, otobus291.class);
    startActivity(newActivity6);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, but having ~290 if statements is definately wrong. Explain your real problem, and we can give you a better solution.

Comment: General tip , use a switch instead of if else if :-)  . ALso your questions is not clear , could you rephrase it?

Comment: Dear god, please tell me you don't really have 290 different classes...

Comment: I want to be opened a new page is clicked listview item. 250 If the number of items running smoothly. but more than 250 "if" or "case"  does not work.

Comment: kcoppock, this is my first application.. suggest what should I do here?

Comment: or Do you have a good resource for developing practice?

Comment: You haven't explained what the difference is in all of those 290 classes. We can only explain what you should do instead if you explain why you have those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do these classes contain, and how do they vary? Most likely, you can have a single activity (`otobus`, in this case), and simply pass the position as an extra, like so:

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, otobus.class);
newActivity.putIntExtra("position", position);
startActivity(newActivity);
```

Then, in the `onCreate()` of your `otobus` Activity, simply handle the layout of the activity based on the position passed:

```
Intent passedIntent = getIntent();
int selectedPosition = passedIntent.getExtra("position", -1);
```